# Is there a paint or update method (rendering loop) in JavaFX2 so that I can update the UI in a loop?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

In Swing you have paint or update(Graphics g) method for each UI component which executes every frame. You can put your drawing logic in the overrided method and draw whatever you want. What is the paint method for JavaFX2 UI?

What I want to do is my UI receives control information from a socket server (another thread). Whenever a control information is received, I should update the UI.

There are two problems:
1. The control information is received from a different thread, it can not access the rendering thread directly.
2. How to update the UI constantly?

For Q1, I have a solution if I know where the update function is (Q2).

I can declare a List object, and insert the new control command received from the socket into the list. In the rendering loop, I can just observe the List object, retrieve the unprocessed command, and delete the already processed command.

However, where can I find such a rendering loop function? I guess maybe I can also do it with javax.concurrent.Task, but I don't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i find the method, I use the following method and it can work. I don't know if there is a better solution

```
  final Duration oneFrameAmt =  Duration.millis(1000/10);

        final KeyFrame oneFrame = new KeyFrame(oneFrameAmt,new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
               //put UI update here                   
            }
        });

        TimelineBuilder.create().cycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE)
                .keyFrames(oneFrame)
                .build()
                .play();
```